# JQuery Validate Options not working MVC3 Razor

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get a simple ignore working for the JQuery validate and I dont seem to be able to get it to work.  No matter what I do it seems to not use the options.  I have trimmed the code down and pasted below.

I am using MVC3 Razor and JQuery 1.5.1

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
    Layout = "~/Areas/Quote/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').validate({
            ignore: "#textx"
        })
    });
</script>
@Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "YourQuote", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "myform"})
    @<input  type="text" id="textx" class="required"/>
    @<input type="submit" value="save" />
End Using
```

The example is simplified but what I really want to do is have an overriding rule which says ignore all hidden elements from validation. My page is dynamically built and removing class and adding them back in when parent elements are hidden or shown is not good for me

```
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
    Layout = "~/Areas/Quote/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myform').validate({
            ignore: ":hidden"
        })
    });
</script>
@Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "YourQuote", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "myform"})
    @<div style="display:none">
    <input  type="text" id="textx" class="required"/>
    </div>
    @<input type="submit" value="save" />
End Using
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks serrghi.  That seems to have done the trick.  How did you figure that out?  And how do I mark that as the answer????

Comment: Changed my comment to a reply :) Glad it worked out for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the unobtrusive jquery inclusion, and just include jquery.validate. I had a similar problem and somehow the unobtrusive library screwed up my custom defined settings

Comment: Thanks, wasted a bunch of time until i found your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `required` class conflicting with the ignore settings? Try removing the class when you want to ignore that field (i.e. if you are conditionally ignoring the field, you will need to use `.removeClass()` in a callback or similar at the appropriate point).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The example is simplified but what I really want to do is have an overriding rule which says ignore all hidden elements from validation.  My page is dynamically built and removing class and adding them back in when parent elements are hidden or shown is not good for me.

Comment: It was just a thought. I'm no expert on jquery-validation, so I'm probably not your man here, but best of luck finding the solution.